# Why getting 404 error in updating via Clickonce tool in vs 2017

Tags: windows, vb.net, clickonce

I am publishing my windows application to a ftp web server and uploading the files succeed but when software is checking the updates then it is giving Error-404

[image: Error 404]

[image: My Signing Setting]

[image: My Security setting]

[image: My publish setting]

[image: My deployment setting]

[image: My Manifest setting]

[image: My updates setting]

Comment: When you insert an image into a question and it prompts you to "enter image description here", you're supposed to enter the image description there. Confusing, I know.

Comment: Clearly, you are using an invalid URL. Use a valid URL and it will work.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i am giving  correct url because in same url i am publishing my application to ftp ,this is working fine.I think if url would be wrong then it must not be uploaded.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between FTP and HTTP?

Comment: No Mr @jmcilhinney

Comment: That's probably part of the problem then. That you have an FTP server on a particular machine does not mean that you have a web server or, if you do, that the path for the file will be the same under both. You need to check what the actual URL of your installer file is and that it has one at all.

Comment: try to use Fiddler to investigate the problem.